# Run simultaneously multiple versions of same feature

Tags: java, scala, jvm

### Context

Running multiple version of the same library seems to be a usual need and there are many questions for this when dealing with *versioned jar* dependencies.

However, I have another constraint here: my code is part of a rolling-release MOAB where code has no version. I cannot depend on a older version of a library from the MOAB.

The use case of that question is being able to load different versions of the same code at runtime for compatibility.

Eg: `GET /my/api/call?compat_version=42`

I have to be able to provide several compatibility versions (*ie* code from version *x* that have not been changed). This must be the actual code that was running when version *x* was the current/latest version and not any kind of retrocompatibility trick.

### Naive solution

The "obvious" way seems to duplicate the code for each version. For instance by having per-version packages:

- `com.me.thing.v1`
- `com.me.thing.v2`
- `com.me.thing.v3`
- ...

and dynamically loading the code from the associate package upon the provided `compat_version` parameter by whatever technique. Let's suppose for know that all those versions share a common interface (API).

### Challenge

I'd like to challenge that and maybe find a better option than the naive solution.

Since using the exact code from version *x* is a prerequisite, I don't believe I can get rid of the copy-paste (but please, tell me I'm wrong).

What technique would you suggest as a simple (but not necessarily easy) and robust implementation? Reflection? Dependency injection?

Is there a "good" pattern for doing such things? Is there any literature on that?

Comment: Probably using different classloaders for the different versions? (Like OSGi does.)

Comment: That would probably be the "simplest" way.

Answer (score 1):

This was already an old problem when Java was developed, hence Sun's emphasis on binary compatibility (which existed for Solaris of course as well). This is the original guarantee offered by the platform- that you can upgrade the bits underneath and applications will continue to work, unmodified.

The way to run legacy code in the JVM world is to run the full legacy application.

Many segregation architectures have of course been developed over the years and reached various levels of maturity- like OSGI and many others before it- but there are edge cases upon edge cases and many failure modes.

Do not futz with multiple code versions within a single JVM. It was never a design goal and in environments where it matters only leads to pain.